# How to increase current in Arduino uno?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

How to increase current in O/P port in Arduino uno ?
to make it 200mA How I can do this?
It can in proggraming add more current
Which sample way to increase current ?
To control 2 Dc motor which normally work with 3 AA battery 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You add a transistor. Just like when you're controlling a relay, which *needs more current that the Arduino can provide*.

Comment: You can use a TT2148 power transistor-this can connect to arduino without a resistor and deal with high current.

Comment: Personally I'd prefer a MOSFET...

Comment: What model of MOSFET do you prefer to use?

Comment: That depends on many factors - current levels, switching speed and voltages, footprint, etc. I have many that I often choose between. One of my current common ones is the TSM2314CX

Comment: The TSM2314CX then. That depends on many factors-state the obvious!

Comment: Which type of transistors I can use?? I can use TIP120 transistor?